# selecting an option on dropdown <select> programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a page on a website that I am updating automatically from a web service. I am trying to set the value of a dropdown `<select>` before the page is loaded and I can see when I select the drop down the value I wanted is already highlighted however I want that option to be selected not highlight. This is my code in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('walkForAmount').selectedIndex = object.get("WalkForTime");
```

which is called automatically when the page is loaded. It sets the selectedIndex to an int 0 -15. And the HTML code:

```
  <select id = "walkForAmount" name="walkForAmount" style="margin-left:2em;margin-top:-1em; width:4em;">
                                <option>-</option>
  </select>
```

Edit: below id the JS I use to generate options

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#walkForAmount").select2({

    }); 

    $("#walkForType").select2({

    });

    for (i = 1; i < 16; i++) {

    $("#walkForAmount").append("<option>"+i+"</option>");

    }

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by selected but not highlighted?

Comment: when I open the drop down the value I want to fill it with is highlighted to tell me that is the selected index but when the page loads the select statement is empty, it just shows the "-"

Comment: where is all the <option>? if you want to have it selected, you need to show us where you generate the options.

Comment: Apologies forgot to add it, even though I already said its filled with int 0-15... didn't really need a down vote.

Comment: to make an option selected, you need to append selected to it: `<option selected value='1'></option>` so you need to check if the current option is one to select, and if so, append the selected option tag instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using Select2, you can update your selection via

```
$("#walkForAmount").select2("val", "5"); // select "5"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/verashn/aWvQr/1/

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any longer. Probably the version.